# Restringing a 7 string bass: Considerations

Tags: electric-bass-guitar, alternative-tunings, string-gauge

I'm considering buying a 7 string bass which is currently strung in standard tuning (B-F in 4ths). I would like to restring it from F# to C, and drop the F# down a step to E.

I'm aware of the tonal range challenges of such low frequencies, but am curious as to advice on what strings would be recommended (prog rock/metal, jazz, classical mainly) and how long I should leave the bass without touching it after restringing etc (basically, any important considerations before during and after restringing).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it's a standard scale bass, then I'd go 45, 65, 85, 105, 130 for the G, D, E, A and  low B.The very low F#/E would be 150/155/160. The top C could be around 30, depending whether you need a bendable top or not.All these are +or- .005, to preferences of easier to fret, or fatter bass tone.

Play it straight away, after the intonation has been adjusted, which is pretty well guaranteed to need doing. The truss rod shouldn't need moving, though.There may be the need to open up holes for the low E, in the bridge or the machine head post, depending on the string you get, as to where it's wound. Sounds like fun - but I'd be inclined to leave the low one at F#, unless you have a very good amp/speaker set up that will do justice to the low E.

Comment: This might be a dozy question, but is that E an octave below 'standard' bottom E for a bass?

Comment: Yes, it's got to be. Basses are usually tuned in 4ths. Standard G,D,A,E. Then down to B and F#. Which is a tone above the note the OP is considering.

Comment: Sounds like some serious engineering, I'd love to see something like that - I'm a bit old school, my Rikki 4001 I've had since the 70s has just the 4 strings ;)

Comment: 8-string basses are rare (F#-F), and unwieldy. 6s are not uncommon, usually B-C. Try a 5-string low B version. That extra string is a boon on the bottom, not particularly for lower notes, but you can stay further up the neck and still find lower ones.I prefer 5-strings all day!

Comment: I've played a 5, many years ago, probably before 6/7/8 was dreamed of - was less confusing than I expected. French hand-made fretless with mag & piezo - was beautiful - wish I could remember the name, always wanted one but was 4 grand at the time, way beyond my wallet.

Comment: Try Bass Collection, by SGC Nanyo, from 80s/90s. Fantastic value - several on Ebay. Very playable, great sounds, a well kept secret. (Until now !)

Comment: I found the one I meant, the Leduc - http://ubass.free.fr/donnees/imgbas/umm6sf.jpg beautiful machine, so expressive

Comment: I use 130s for my low B, so wouldn't you need something a bit thicker for a low F#? (especially if tuned down a step)

Comment: @Basstickler - well spotted !! My low Bs are 125/ 130 ! Call it a typo. Edited to hopefully make some sense !

Comment: Nice.  I'm not sure I would need it but this bass sounds like fun.  I have a cool six-string that is setup with a 4pack of flatwounds and an A and D strings from a flatwound guitar set. Tuned from D to Eb.  Fun for bass chords and I use it a lot when recording to get a lead sound (I am awful at guitar).